# How to filter urls with # (hash tag) using UrlFilter in a chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've just started building a chrome extension and as I need to display its icon only for specific urls, I used [page_action](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction&sa=U&ei=y-AbVO64HbjLsATX4oHYDA&ved=0CAUQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNFVPIA4uvojEDwbZZcxKoJ0URmOFQ).
I also used an event listening if the url changes and matches my pattern that way to display the icon:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
{
    conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'https://mysite.com/mypage.html' }
        })
    ],
    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
}
]);
```

It works fine but when I want to add a filter of the first character of the query, it fails.
The url pattern I want to filter looks like: 
https://mysite.com/mypage.html#e123456789

I tried the following but it didn't help:

```
pageUrl: { urlContains: 'https://mysite.com/mypage.html#e' }
pageUrl: { urlContains: 'https://mysite.com/mypage.html', queryPrefix: '#e' }
pageUrl: { urlContains: 'https://mysite.com/mypage.html', queryPrefix: 'e' }
```

I think that the issue comes from the hash tag.

Any idea of a workaround ?

Comment: Try `pathContains` instead. If it works, I'll make that into an answer.

Comment: Hi Xan, thanks for your quick answer but for some reasons it doesn't work neither. It looks like it can't check what's after the hash tag.

Comment: Which is kind of strange. I would file a feature request on https://crbug.com and see what they have to say.

Answer (score 2):

The `#...` part of a URL is called a "reference fragment" (ocassionally referred to as "hash").

Reference fragments are currently not supported in [URLFilters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter), there is already a bug report for this feature: [Issue 84024: targetUrlPatterns and URL search/hash component](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84024).

If you really want to show the page action depending on the state of the reference fragment, then you could use the [`chrome.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onReferenceFragmentUpdated) event instead of the declarativeContent API. For example (adapted from my answer to [How to show Chrome Extension on certain domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855956/how-to-show-chrome-extension-on-certain-domains/20856789#20856789); see that answer for the `manifest.json` to use for testing):

```js
function onWebNav(details) {
    var refIndex = details.url.indexOf('#');
    var ref = refIndex >= 0 ? details.url.slice(refIndex+1) : '';
    if (ref.indexOf('e') == 0) { // Starts with e? show page action
        chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
    } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(details.tabId);
    }
}
// Base filter
var filter = {
    url: [{
        hostEquals: 'example.com'
    }]
};
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid actions being triggered when a # link is clicked on a page? (this is the only related answer I've found). I'm testing a `rule` with a `PageStateMatcher` which includes `pathEquals: '/menu'`. Internal page links modify the URL (eg: /menu#settings) and this causes all my scripts to be injected again.

Comment: @IvanRF In your script, check whether a global variable exists before continuing, and afterwards set this global variable to make sure that the script runs once.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18423519/1718678), but I wanted to know if I was missing something about `rules` :)