# Call content script on URL change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm new to Chrome extensions. I know there's lots of similar questions and info out there, but none of it seems to address this problem.

I need my content script to execute on every page that matches `*://*.youtube.com/watch?v=*`.

I've tried using the above value and `*://*.youtube.com/*` as the match property, but neither works supposedly due to the way YouTube handles requests. I've also tried using the `onhashchange` event, but of course YouTube doesn't use anchors in their URLs. I've read about `webRequest`, but I don't need the function to be called when somebody is scrolling through the comments and the page loads more comments.

**All I need is a way to call my content script when the URL changes. How exactly can I accomplish this?**

Additionally, I cannot load the content script at `document_start` because the extension scrapes the HTML and parses it.

Comment: @wOxxOm your solution doesn't work for me... i cannot execute the content script at `document_start` because the extension scrapes the HTML and parses it

Comment: Then simply use [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation)'s history events shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932741)

Comment: that's exactly what i am looking into right now. but can webNavigation even be used with a content script?? also, youtube doesn't use hashes??

Comment: No, it cannot be used in a content script, which is exactly why I've suggested it as I misunderstood your comment about document_start. Also, url-hash change is only one event of the three shown in that link, simply use the other two. If you want to do it in a content script then my [initial suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077641/how-to-detect-page-navigation-on-youtube-and-modify-html-before-page-is-rendered/34100952?s=3|0.1801#34100952) can be used because document_start is not an absolute requirement.

Comment: @wOxxOm your solution in your other answer doesn't work since my content script is executed at `document_end`, and by that time the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already come and gone. additionally, the `spfdone` event is never called either. what events should i rebind those listeners to if not `DOMContentLoaded` or `spfdone`?

Comment: That answer is an example. In your case there's no need for DOMContentLoaded at all: you can scrape the initial DOM immediately. Also, spfdone is triggered for me https://puu.sh/wRCVm/fa465cfb19.png when another video page is loaded, which is what this event is for.

Comment: @wOxxOm i know it was an example. i got it working. i just removed the document listener and called the function within the content script. [this chosen solution also worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865581/chrome-extension-content-script-not-loaded-until-page-is-refreshed/21071357#21071357) ... never mind your solution still doesn't work lol

Comment: @wOxxOm i jumped the gun when i said "this chosen solution also worked". it works to the extent that it executes the content script when the history changes, but even with `runAt: 'document_idle'` it executes **way** too early, which breaks the functionality of my extension :/

Comment: The new event used by youtube is `yt-navigate-start` on `window`, which you can discover by running `getEventListeners(window)` in devtools console. So simply attach event listener for that event and also for `load` on `window` for the first run of the content script.

Comment: I've [edited that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952/) to provide a more generalized approach.

Comment: @wOxxOm okay, it works now. that was the issue, that i'm using the new YT. however, i'm running into the exact same issue as `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, which is that the script executes wayyy **too early**. my script needs to run **after** a script in the website's `body` is executed :.( the idea that i thought of last night would be maybe sending messages back and forth? maybe that's the best idea?

Comment: Well, you can wait for the element produced by that script by using MutationObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm sweet. i'll look into that right now **<3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077641/how-to-detect-page-navigation-on-youtube-and-modify-html-before-page-is-rendered)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what I did. I added a background script to listen to all changes

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            message: 'hello',
            url: changeInfo.url
        });
    }
});
```

Then in my content script, I listen to it and reload the URL

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === 'hello') {
            const { url } = request;
            chrome.location.replace(url);
        }

});
```